# Firebase Transactions null or not updating the first time thru

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have clients connecting to the database with javascript.
I also have code running on my server and I'm trying to do a transaction following example as shown here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/save-data#section-transactions

Here's a simplified structure of my data

```
 users:
    userguid
       resource : "room1"
       printer :  "printer1"



resources
    rooms
        room1
           printers
              printer1
                counter : 15
```

The web client would write a request to their own node under "users".

The server is watching for those request and updates the counter for that resource.

If i have the transaction watching for child added I get null for counter so I can't increment the number.  If I also watch for child modified the I will get the correct counter value.

I understand from the documentation that the value in transaction can be null but I'm not sure how I can fix my use case to do what I need.

Basically I don't want the client touching the counter, I want the server to read and update that value.

I've gone thru this post
[Firebase runTransaction not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818946/firebase-runtransaction-not-working)
but I'm not clear on how to structure my code to deal with this.