# Android Firebase Database Exception while runTransaction

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `TransactionHandler` to push a data object as there can be concurrency issues. but while doing that I am getting the below exception:

```
09-15 19:12:20.193 3196-3196/com.teja.twaters D/com.teja.twaters.utils.FirebaseUtil: isComplete - false
09-15 19:12:20.207 3196-3196/com.teja.twaters D/com.teja.twaters.utils.FirebaseUtil: databaseError - DatabaseError: User code called from the Firebase Database runloop threw an exception:
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1037KB
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzbw(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln.zzcd(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaln$zza.zzce(
```

I did search for this exception during `runTransaction`, but couldn't find any. Below is the code snippet where I get this exception:

```
dataSnapshot.getRef().runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {       
@Override 
public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) { 
    mutableData.child(order.getId() + "").setValue(order);        
    return Transaction.success(mutableData);     
}      
@Override 
public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean isComplete,    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 
    logger.debug("isComplete - " + isComplete); 
    if(isComplete){ 
        logger.debug("dataSnapshot - " + dataSnapshot); 
        callback.onSuccess(IConstants.USER_ORDER_SAVED);
    } else { 
        logger.debug("databaseError - " + databaseError); 
        callback.onSuccess(IConstants.USER_ORDER_SAVE_FAILED);         
    }     
}
```

});

I get this only with `runTransaction`. But `setValue` for a child and `updateChildren` are working good. Someone else faced with this scenario?

**UPDATE:**

The root cause i found is that, the Order POJO I was using has a sub-class which was not declared as static. I changed that, and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The appearance of `dataSnapshot.getRef()` in the code you posted is a clue that the code is running inside a listener callback.  Let's say the listener is on location X.  When you call `dataSnapshot.getRef().runTransaction()`, you are requesting the transaction on the value at location X.  That value is the `MutableData` you get in the `doTransaction()` callback.  In the `doTransaction()` callback, you are setting the value of a child of X, which is also a change to X itself.  This causes the listener to fire again. I suspect that is the loop that is causing  the stack overflow.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35819073/4815718) provides the details of how transactions are performed.  It might be helpful.

Comment: Hi qbix, thanks for the reply. But i found out, the root cause is all together is different. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

For further readers... I had the problem that I had a method inside of my 
POJO called `getDBReference`(), which was not static and returned the

```
DatabaseReference
```

to this POJO instance. Which, then in a transaction was falsely detected by reflection to "add" to the transaction and caused a StackOverFlow.

tl;dr

I forgot to annotate this method with `@Exclude`, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if u call FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() at several place .  You should create a singleton instance of it and then use it throught out your project .
Example :

public class FirebaseUtils{
private static FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

```
public static FirebaseDatabase getDatabase() {
    if (mDatabase == null) {
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    }
    return mDatabase;
} }
```

and get the database FirebaseUtils.getDatabase();