# Get the current state in a transaction operation in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, null

I have created a script that performs a request with firebase. Since I want to avoid multiple queries on a relation at the same time, I use the transaction function as seen in the code. First, I get the current status of the relation and check if it is present or not. This seems to work. The first time is const `current = null` and the function to add value to `data2` will be executed.
And if I run the script the second time, then he goes into the next function successfully (`doSecondFunction()`).
And unfortunately, no currentData returns to me here. I expect the value of the ref `data2` that was added the first time. But as a result, I get `null`.
Is there a way to work in the transaction with the current state of the database?

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('data2');
    ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        const current = snapshot.val();

                if(current == null){
                    console.log('FIRST');
                    addValToRefFunction();
                }else{
                    console.log('SECOND');
                    doSecondFunction(current, ref);
                }
            });

function doSecondFunction(current, ref){
                ref.transaction(function(currentData){
                    console.log(current); // result is the right value  
                    console.log(currentData); // result is null ?
                    if (currentData === current){
                        console.log('Check');
                        return;
            }         
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way control what the client sees as the current status of a node when starting a transaction. In my experience the first time the callback gets invoked, the value is almost always `null`, and the callback needs to handle that.

Also see my answer here for a description of the process: [Firebase runTransaction not working - MutableData is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818946/firebase-runtransaction-not-working-mutabledata-is-null/35819073#35819073)

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a code example that a callback handle that?

Comment: Check for `if (current == null)` in your transaction callback, similar to what you do in the `value` callback.