# Deleting a node using a transaction not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete a node from my Firebase real-time database using a transaction. I am using a transaction in order to make the user aware if he/she was the one deleting it, or if someone else deleted it just before they could.

**This code doesn't work! (P is always null) unless I call the transaction method twice consecutively, then it is not null in the second call. Why?**

```
mBookedSlotsNodeReference.child(booking.getUserUid())                 
.child(String.valueOf(booking.getStartTime())).runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

  @Override
  public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
        BookedSlot p = mutableData.getValue(BookedSlot.class); // Checked in debug mode, and the value is null!
                    if (p != null) { 
                        //Delete BookedSlot
                        mutableData.setValue(null);
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    } else {
                        Log.e("Error","Node doesn't exist");
                        return Transaction.abort();
                    }

                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b,
                                       DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Transaction completed
                    if (databaseError == null) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                            Log.e("Success","node deleted!");
                           } else {
                            Log.e("fail","something wierd happened!");
                           }
                    } else {
                      Log.e("db error", databaseError.getDetails()); 
                    }
                }
            });
```

---

**If I query for the node, it is present! But, why is it not found using the transaction?**

```
 mBookedSlotsNodeReference.child(booking.getUserUid())
                    .child(String.valueOf(booking.getStartTime())).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    dataSnapshot.getValue();// Checked in debug mode, and the value is correct!

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

---

Firebase DB structure:

```
Root{
   BookedSlots{
           UserUID{
                   UnixTimeStamp:
                                classRoom:
                                UnixTimeStamp:
                                UserUID:
                   }
          }
    }
```

---

BookedSlot pojo:

```
public class BookedSlot {
    private long UnixTimeStamp;
    private String classRoom;
    private String UserUID;

public BookedSlot() {
    }
 //getters + setters
```

I am testing the sample app alone, so there is no chance of any entries getting written just after i delete one, or any kind of concurrent entries.

Am I doing something wrong here?

**N.B: If I call the transaction method twice, the mutableData is not Null in the second call!!! So, it works correctly!**

**Am I doing something wrong here?**

Comment: Is `mutableData` also null?

Comment: @sanoJ Yes, MutableData { key = <none>, value = null }

Comment: Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/35819073/9263083